# Testing cellphone speakers out of circuit

Tags: speakers

What is the best low cost way to test a cellphone speaker out of circuit at the test bench level?

Comment: With a signal generator? You'll have to estimate a suitable power level.

Comment: 555 timer with amplifier IC would be one of the lowest cost options without requiring instruments

Comment: What would you be testing: Coil continuity, or sound output clarity? Piezo speakers used in some phones will fail a continuity test, as they do not have a coil, they essentially behave electrically like capacitors. They will also fail (or be barely audible in) a click test, as they are driven with 12 or 24 Volts or even higher in some cases. In older paper or plastic cone speakers (rare in modern cellphones) a damaged cone can generate buzzing or weak sound, even when the coil has continuity, so a click test would pass but sound test would show the speaker is unusable. Add more details please.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do a good/bad test on a speaker is with a 1.5 V battery and a 100 Ω resistor in series.  If the speaker is working, you will hear clicks as the connection is made and broken.

Instead of a battery, you can use a bench supply, like 5 V.  In that case use 300-500 Ω.  The point of the resistor is to limit the current to 10-15 mA.  That should be enough to cause something audible, but below what could damage even a small speaker.